# I don't know what's wrong with the program

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

variable "code" doesn't change (str) when i check and if i put checkbox() above codeget() there will be no checkbox
how to fix there is code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *

#Window
window = Tk()
window.title("Register") #set window title
window.geometry('900x500')

code = 'None'

def codeget():
    if (var1.get() == 1) and (var2.get() == 0):
        code = 'Python'
    elif (var1.get() == 0) and (var2.get() == 1):
        code = 'C++'
    elif (var1.get() == 0) and (var2.get() == 0):
        code = 'None'
    else:
        code = 'Both'

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
c1 = Checkbutton(window, text='Python',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=codeget)
c1.place(x=650,y=120)
c2 = Checkbutton(window, text='C++',variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=codeget)
c2.place(x=720,y=120)

def luu():
    s=open("saveaccount", 'a+')
    accountin4 = '\n' + 'Code: ' + code
    s.write(accountin4)

message = Button(window,text = "Register", command = luu)
message.place(x = 500, y = 370)

mainloop()
```

if and else may not be related to my question so you can ignore it, even if I use = to assign " " to the code, the result will still be "None"

Comment: You do not assign anything to *code*. Also, use *and* instead of *&* in this context

Comment: `code` is local to the function and `==` is not an assignment.

Comment: so how to assign new variable to code, i tried = and ==

Comment: ... and in `save` function else without if ...

Comment: in my python file i have a if else but i delete it to be able to post

Comment: The save function is not an important for the rest of the code so can be ignored in relation to your question, but why couldn't you post code with the 'if' statement included and why does it have a **return** statement? To assign code a new value use '='  as in **code = 'Python'**, but what are you then going to do with **code**, it is not used anywhere else in your code so you wont know if it changes?

Comment: `code` is local variable inside `codeget()` . You have to add `global code` inside function to inform function that it has to assign value to global variable instead of creating local variable `code`

Answer (score 0):

`codeget()` creates local variable `code`. You have to add `global code` inside this function to inform function that it has to assign value to global variable `code` instead of creating local variable `code`.

---

Minimal working code with small other changes.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def get_code():  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables
    global code  # inform function to assign to global variable `code` instead of creating local variable `code`
    
    if var1.get() == 0 and var2.get() == 0:
        code = 'None'
    elif var1.get() == 1 and var2.get() == 0:
        code = 'Python'
    elif var1.get() == 0 and var2.get() == 1:
        code = 'C++'
    else:
        code = 'Both'

def register():  # PEP8: readable name
    s = open("saveaccount", 'a+')
    text = '\n' + 'Code: ' + code
    s.write(text)
    s.close()   # better close file because system may keep data in buffer in RAM and write data when you close file
    print(text)

# --- main ---

code = 'None'  # it is global variable

window = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Python', variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=get_code)
c1.pack()

c2 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='C++', variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=get_code)
c2.pack()

message = tk.Button(window, text="Register", command=register)
message.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to use more checkbuttons then you could use `for`-loop to create them, and `StringVar` to use string `onvalue="Python"` instead of integers `0/1`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def get_code():
    global code  # inform function to assign to global variable `code` instead of creating local variable `code`
    
    selected = []

    for v in string_vars:
        if v.get():
            selected.append(v.get())

    if not selected:
        code = 'None'
    else:
        code = ','.join(selected)

def register():
    s = open("saveaccount", 'a+')
    text = '\n' + 'Code: ' + code
    print(text)
    s.write(text)
    s.close()

# --- main ---

code = 'None'  # it is global variable

window = tk.Tk()

string_vars = []

for item in ['Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'PHP', 'Rust', 'Go']:
    v = tk.StringVar(window)
    c = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=item, variable=v, onvalue=item, offvalue='', command=get_code)
    c.pack()
    string_vars.append(v)

message = tk.Button(window, text="Register", command=register)
message.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]